# Cannot access implemented property (from interface)

Tags: c#, .net, syntax

I have an interface with properties:

```
public interface IEntityModifier
{

    ...
    bool AutoDetachOnFinished { get; set; }
    bool Finished { get; }
    ...

}
```

Then I implement it:

```
    bool IEntityModifier.AutoDetachOnFinished { get; set; }
    bool IEntityModifier.Finished { get { return this.mFinished; } }
```

But when I need to access `AutoDetachOnFinished` within the same class, a compiler error pops out:

```
    void IEntityModifier.Update(IEntity pEntity, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameTime pGameTime)
    {
        if (!this.mFinished)
        {
            this.Value += this.Delta * (float)pGameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

            if (this.Value >= this.Max)
            {
                this.Value = this.Max;
                this.mFinished = true;
                if (this.AutoDetachOnFinished) { /* Error Here */ }
            }
        }
    }
```

The error message:

> 14    'MEngine.Entities.EntityModifier.SingleValueEntityModifier' does
>   not contain a definition for 'AutoDetachOnFinished' and no extension
>   method 'AutoDetachOnFinished' accepting a first argument of type
>   'MEngine.Entities.EntityModifier.SingleValueEntityModifier' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

I have 2 questions:

1. Why does the compiler complain if I delete `IEntityModifier.`s (so `IEntityModifier.Update` would become `Update`, apply to any implemented method)?
2. Why can't I access `AutoDetachOnFinished`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have implemented these as [explicit interface implementations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms173157.aspx), meaning you can only access them through a variable of the interface type - `IEntityModifier`.

Either do that:

```
if (((IEntityModifier)this).AutoDetachOnFinished)
```

or remove the interface name from the implementation:

```
bool AutoDetachOnFinished { get; set; }
bool Finished { get { return this.mFinished; } }
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you are implementing the interface explicitly.

```
bool IEntityModifier.AutoDetachOnFinished { get; set; }
```

You must cast to the interface in order access explicit implementations. Perhaps not what you want. So remove the interface name from the implementation

```
bool AutoDetachOnFinished { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert this.AutoDetachOnFinished to object of type IEntityModifier as you are doing           explicit Interface implementation. [here some explanation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
  IEntityModifier entitymodifier=(IEntityModifier)objectInstanceOfimplementedClass;

     if( entitymodifier.AutoDetachOnFinished)
```